# Xcode - configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH

Tags: ruby, xcode, gcc, compiler-errors, rvm

rebuilding a mac from scratch.  Installed xcode and rvm then trying to install rubies but they are all giving me:

```
Error running ' ./configure --prefix=/Users/durrantm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125 
--enable-shared --disable-install-doc --with-libyaml 
--with-opt-dir=/Users/durrantm/.rvm/usr ', 
please read /Users/durrantm/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p125/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
Michaels-MacBook-Air:~ durrantm$
```

The log has:

```
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/Users/durrantm/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p290':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
```

Do I need the gcc C compliler? How do I install it ?

Comment: https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer

Comment: Yes. It seems you need some kind of c compiler, and you have none.

Comment: XCode includes GCC; perhaps your `$PATH` is hosed?

Answer (score 176, accepted):

### The critical step is actually *installing* the **Xcode command line tools** *after* the download completes *and* Xcode is installed

After downloading and installing Xcode from the app store, you need to actually install the command line tools it provides.
To do this open Xcode, go to preferences then downloads.  There is an "Install" link to add the command line tools.

Once this has been completed, make sure to re-open your terminal window.

Comment: +1 for adding info about installing the Xcode Command Line Tools

Comment: Brilliant comment, saved me tons of time.

Comment: How could I know without seeing this answer??? Thanks for pointing this out! BTW mine works without reopening my terminal window.

Comment: I have been strugling two days before I find this answer. +1 for pointing out the Xcode CL tools. I am now able to install and use Xdebug

Answer (score 10):

Either you install Xcode from the App store or if you have a registered free developer account you can download the XCode command line tools from http://developer.apple.com/downloads

Once you have that installed you can go ahead and install your rubies with rvm.

Comment: XCode version above 4.x is required.

Answer (score 2):

rbenv install error :

```
configure: error: in `/tmp/ruby-build.20130911002344.31969/ruby-2.0.0-p0':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
```

...brought me here,

I am currently installing Ruby on rails, ruby through rbenv on a brand new Debian,

Original command is :

```
rbenv install 2.0.0-p0
```

As a solution :

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Cheers !

[Sorry for the Xcode ppl]

Answer (score 0):

Read `rvm requirements` it shows what you need to compile ruby.