# RVM not able to install different versions of Ruby

Tags: ruby, terminal, rvm

I've been following all the instructions on http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/ and http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/basics/

In the terminal I can type in "type rvm" and it says "rvm is a function" so it's supposed to have installed correctly.

Now, when I type in something like: rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p318, rvm install 1.9.2 or anything else that seems to run the install process I get the following errors

```
Error running 'make ', please read /Users/Nick/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p318/yaml/make.log
Error running ' ./configure --prefix=/Users/Nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318 --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --with-libyaml --with-opt-dir=/Users/Nick/.rvm/usr ', please read /Users/Nick/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p318/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
ls: /Users/Nick/.rvm/rubies/*/bin/ruby: No such file or directory
```

So I opened the install.log file and it says this:

```
configure: error: in `/Users/Nick/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
```

There is no config.log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to install Xcode Command Line tools, so you can compile RVM on installation. I believe just installing Xcode will do it.

Answer (score 4):

You need a C compiler and it seems you have none installed or it's not on your path. XCode provides one, have you installed it?

Check this similar question [Xcode - configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323612/configure-error-no-acceptable-c-compiler-found-in-path)

Comment: I ran "rvm requirements" and it says that in order to install 1.9.3 I have to first have the libksba. 

So I googled how to download that and it says I need homebrew. So now I'm installing homebrew.

Now it says that I need xcode in order to install homebrew. 

lol...

Comment: I downloaded xcode commandline tools and re-ran homebrew doctor. the error messages changed a bit. I get the error "Warning: /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin
This means that system-provided programs will be used instead of those
provided by Homebrew. The following tools exist at both paths:

    git
    git-cvsserver
    git-receive-pack
    git-shell
    git-upload-archive
    git-upload-pack
    gitk

Consider amending your PATH so that /usr/local/bin
is ahead of /usr/bin in your PATH."

I'm downloading xcode but it's going to take an hour or so to finish.

Comment: I have no idea what to do in order to switch those things in the PATH. I don't even know what that is, or how to find it lol

Comment: I don't think homebrew is revelant in this case (never used it myself, so I might be wrong). But, after installing XCode, open a Terminal and run `gcc`. If the result is something like this: `i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: no input files`, then gcc is installed, so try again installing ruby. If the result is something like `command not found` check @jbm-hack answer on http://superuser.com/questions/313107/does-updating-to-os-x-lion-delete-gcc and see it that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Just a sidenote: Even with XCode installed you may run into similar problem. The solution is here: [Can't install Ruby under Lion with RVM – GCC issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032824/cant-install-ruby-under-lion-with-rvm-gcc-issues)