# Installing RVM getting errors with configure

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

I'm getting errors installing RVM, I have installed Ruby 2.0.0 with brew, and now I'm trying to run the RVM command at http://www.rvm.io

```
Error running './configure --prefix=/Users/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/libxml2:/usr/local/opt/libxslt:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/openssl:/usr/local/opt/sqlite --disable-install-doc --without-tcl --without-tk --enable-shared',
please read /Users/name/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

This is what my log looks like

```
[2013-04-10 21:50:21] ./configure
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --without-tcl, --without-tk
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin12.3.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin12.3.0
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin12.3.0
checking for gcc-4.2... no
checking for clang... no
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/Users/name/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p0':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
```

I have Xcode installed too.

Comment: Generally you use RVM to install ruby, is there a reason you installed it via homebrew first?

Comment: Do you have the command tools installed?

Comment: @DanFairaizl hmm, it was because I saw it on the ruby website that mac osx you can just do brew install.

Comment: @fmendez I will try to see if I have it installed... Edit: I have not installed it, per Jorge's answer below. I will do that now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have Xcode installed? You then have to go into its preference window to install the command line tools. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323612/xcode-configure-error-no-acceptable-c-compiler-found-in-path).

Comment: Thanks! I haven't installed it, so it seems... I will install it and then check if RVM will work again.

Comment: This works, but i'm having problems with rubygems, i guess thats another question to be asked.

Comment: @andrewliu Indeed I would agree. Glad I could help with this problem though.